# ESLintで名前付き引数でErrorが出ないようにする方法

Tags: javascript, eslint

## 環境

- Node.js v10.10.0
- ESLint v5.13.0

## 質問

以下のコードの名前付き引数min, maxで、Errorが発生します。

```js
const randomIndex = random.int(min=0, max=10);
```

```
error  'min' is not defined  no-undef 
error  'max' is not defined  no-undef
```

どのような設定を行えば、警告が消えますか？

## .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            4
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "no-console": 0
    }
};
```

## 参考

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単純にJSに名前付き引数という構文はないためエラーになっているのかと思います。
元のコードは以下のコードのように解釈されます。

```
min = 0
max = 10
const randomIndex = random.int(min,max);
```

min,maxは変数として解釈され、その変数にvar(またはlet,const)がついていないためes-lintがエラーを吐いています。

単純にエラーを消したいだけなら

```
const randomIndex = random.int(0,10);
```

と書けば解決します。

別の方法で名前付き引数のような書き方をしたいのであれば、引数をObjectで受け取る方法があります。
その場合randomInt()側も修正が必要です。

```
const randomInt = ({min,max})=>{
  // randomIntの処理
}
const randomIndex = randomInt({min:0,max:10});
```

Comment: 補足として、質問者さんが使用していると思われるモジュール[random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random)のサンプルでなぜかこの擬似“名前付き引数”が使用されているようです。この書き方はstrictモードでは利用できないなどデメリットが多いし、randomモジュールの利用に必須ではないので、回答者さんのおっしゃる通り`min =`や`max =`を消すのが一番よいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「JavaScriptに名前付き引数がある」と勘違いした状態で、質問していました。